# How to search for a pattern of strings through a list of strings and return the respective indexes?

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, nlp

I have already thought of some solutions in order to try to solve the problem but none seems to me to be appropriate. I'm gonna explain:

Let's imagine that we have the following list of strings (sequence of PoS tags from Part of Speech Tagging):

**['PROPN', 'AUX', 'ADV', 'VERB', 'SCONJ', 'PROPN', 'AUX', 'NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'PROPN', 'AUX', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT']**

My goal is to find the following pattern in the list:

**PROPN - AUX - (ANYTHING IN BETWEEN) - PUNCT**

by returning these two possible results:

**[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]** and **[9,10,11,12]**

I know that one of the possible ways would be to concatenate all the strings in the list and use regex in python but that method will have a problem:

The indexes that would match are related only with the indexes of the characters of the that string and, after that, it will not be adequate (in my opinion) to convert these indexes to the indexes of the positions of the words in the original list. It is important to maintain the integrity of the tokenization that is done in the initial list.

I would be grateful if someone could propose me a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Pattern search is a well-covered topic in computing; we expect to see a *specific* coding problem.  Asking for help to design your particular solution, is out of scope for Stack Overflowl

Comment: Please do not put language tags in the title.

Comment: Check out regexp theory. This problem is identical to finding the pattern `ab.*c` in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution in Python:

```
def match_indexes(probelist, head=['PROPN', 'AUX'], tail=['PUNCT']):
    """ returns a list with all indexes in a list of strings that matches 
        prefix and tail 
    """
    result=list()
    step = len(head)
    last = len(probelist) - len(tail)
    if (step + len(tail) <= len(probelist)):
        for i in range(0,last):
            if (probelist[i:i+len(head)] == head):
                for j in range (i+step,last + 1):
                    if probelist[j:j+len(tail)] == tail:
                        result.append(list(range(i,j+len(tail))))
    return result
```

Note that all arguments are passed as lists. You can start from here.

Sample output:

> ```
> test = ['PROPN', 'AUX', 'ADV', 'VERB', 'SCONJ', 'PROPN', 'AUX', \
>           'NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'PROPN', 'AUX', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT']
>
> print( match_indexes(test)) 
> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
> 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
>
> print(match_indexes(test,head=['NOUN'])) 
> [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [11,12]]
>
> print(match_indexes(test, head=['NOUN'], tail=["PROPN"]))
> [[7, 8, 9]]
>
> print(match_indexes(test, head=['PROPN', 'NOUN'], tail=["PROPN"])) 
> []
>
> test = [] print(match_indexes(test))
> []
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much @silver. This solution corresponds exactly to what I needed.